# Python File Read/Write - Appending the Wrong Text

Tags: python, file, append

Trying to mess around with python's file editing functionality and I think I'm missing something. I'm trying to append a string to a text file (pretty basic stuff), but it's appending the wrong text somehow.

Code:

```
file = open("test.hxm", "a")
file.write("alsdkjfsd")
file.close()
```

Content stored in test.hxm after running:

```
慬獤歪晳
```

No errors, and it happens every time. I delete the text, re run, same deal. Am I missing something obvious about these functions that's messing it up? At first I thought that I was opening the file in bytes mode instead of text mode, but changing the mode to "at" doesn't change anything. At a total loss.

EDIT: Worked it out. As people were saying, the above code works fine. Ended up deleting my test file, creating a new file with the same name, and then everything worked fine. No idea what caused this, but it ended up working.

Comment: Works as intended for me, have you tried `file = open("test.hxm", "a", encoding="utf-8")
` ?

Comment: It works for me. Try opening the file in ```encoding='utf-8'```

Comment: Your `open()` call does not specify a folder, so you are writing to what Python thinks is the current working directory. That is very often not what novices expect. Are you *very* sure the file you are looking at is the one you are writing to? Look at the timestamp to verify. Or specify a full path for the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 file = open("test.hxm", "a")
 file.write("alsdkjfsd")
 file.close()
```

this is working fine :)

I open this file in vs code and also using a Windows text editor to open

Comment: *open files in text format*?  Then which format is this?

Comment: fascinating! glad that my code is working at least. i'll keep monkeying around. thanks!